# Arrays and files with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, file

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

I'm searching for the best way to write an Array into a file and to be able to get it back (in another Array later)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize your array with [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html), [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) or even [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) if it contains only strings and numbers.

Comment: ok, thank you i will look at those unknown things :)

Answer (score 0):

With ruby there are many ways to do the same thing, I would recommend looking at the IO class http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-write

IO.read and the IO.write are possible methods to do this.